# Hibernate Spatial Maven Issue

Tags: postgis, hibernate-spatial

I'm following the tutorial at http://www.hibernatespatial.org/tutorial-hs4.html. I've created a maven project, and imported it into Eclipse. However, when I run `mvn dependency:list`, I get the error `Missing artifact org.postgis:postgis-jdbc:jar:1.5.3`. The same error is reported from within Eclipse. Any idea on what I may be doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I sorted this issue by:
1. Added maven-compiler-plugin dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.1</version>
</dependency>
```

1. Added postgis-jdbc dependency that is available in the maven repository. As it turns out, version 1.5.3 is not available in the maven repository, and I was not in the mood to compile the jar. So, I just added:

> ```
> <dependency>
>     <groupId>org.postgis</groupId>
>     <artifactId>postgis-jdbc</artifactId>
>     <version>1.3.3</version>
> </dependency>
> ```

And that sorted it out.

Comment: postgis-jdbc dependency could as well be replaced with version 1.5.2, which is also available in the maven repository.

Comment: @RyanDalton, sorry for the delay.